# Build errors in run command for azure function project

Tags: azure, azure-functions, java-11

I am running azure project
and getting the following error

> Azure Functions Core Tools
> Core Tools Version: 3.0.3216 Commit hash: 91e025087513e9e0f3ad02442e35e2f58b40d1b3
> Function Runtime Version: 3.0.15193.0
> Skipping 'JAVA_HOME' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
> [2022-05-16T14:25:28.863Z] File 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is not found, 'dotnet' invocation will rely on the PATH environment variable.
> [2022-05-16T14:25:39.649Z] File 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is not found, 'dotnet' invocation will rely on the PATH environment variable.
> [2022-05-16T14:25:40.239Z] File 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is not found, 'dotnet' invocation will rely on the PATH environment variable.
> [2022-05-16T14:25:40.646Z] File 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is not found, 'dotnet' invocation will rely on the PATH environment variable.
> [2022-05-16T14:25:40.727Z] Worker process started and initialized.

i have Installed `AzureFunction tool` in the system and `install Azure Toolkit Plugin  in intellij`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please check the below steps if it helps to, as it is working from our end**:

1. > File 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is not found, 'dotnet' invocation will rely on the PATH environment variable.

It looks like dotnet is not included in the System Environment Variables Path.

**How to find this**?

Click on Windows  Search Button > Type Environment Variables > Open and Click ️ on Environment Variables > check these paths available in your system:

[image]

If dotnet is not found, install the latest [SDK of dotnet](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) and check after installing using the command in the command prompt: `dotnet --version`.

If any of the paths are not available, include those in Environment Variables of the System.

**Also, check user variables in the same dialog box:**

[image]

After this, once check the required tools installed and steps mentioned in this [MSFT Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij) are followed and then try running the function.

Comment: We are using java and build tool gradle in our project . Do we need to install dotnet

Comment: Yes, could you please install and try once!

Comment: @HariKrishna I was having the same problem with my Python function and your answer solved it. Can you please let me know why dotnet is needed here, if we are working on other languages like python, JAVA?